# starling framework animation is choppy on enter frame

Tags: starling-framework

I have created a basic as3 web project with starling. All iam doing is creating a simple image and in onEnterframe moving the image along x. But it seems that the animation/movement is not smooth, there is a jump in frames/jerkiness after every few frames. Below is onEnterFrame and the test function used to create the image. Any help on this is much appreciated.

```
    private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        if(!img)
            return;
        img.x += 1;

        if(img.x >= 960)
            img.x = 0;
    }

    private function test():void
    {
          img = new Image(sAssets.getTextureAtlas("atlas").getTexture("flight_00"));
          addChild(img);
          img.x = 0;
          img.y = 320;
    }
```

Comment: are you using Starling's onEnterFrame event?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the time of each frame is slightly different. To achieve smooth animation, declare onEnterFrame handler with passedTime argument (that stores the time passed since previous frame) and use this value to move objects, instead of assuming that each frame will last 1/frameRate sec.

```
private function onEnterFrame(passedTime:Number):void
{
    if(!img)
        return;

    img.x += passedTime * 100; // speed is 100 px/sec

    if(img.x >= 960)
        img.x = 0;
}
```

Note: this form of event handlers (without event argument) is supported in recent versions of Starling, and should be more performant. If you use older version, you can obtain passed time from the corresponding property of event object.